# Configuring a network on Ubuntu virtual machines

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, wep

I want to set up two Ubuntu virtual machines. One of them needs to be connected to a router with a WEP encryption. I have the router set up and have one VM connected to it.

**My question is:**
How can I set up the second VM to where it has no authorization to the network, but can still see the network through the `iwlist` command?
I am doing a project on cracking the WEP encryption and need to set up the environment.

**EDIT:**
I am using VirtualBox on MacBook.

Comment: You need a second WiFi device and not connect it with the password? What is the problem exactly?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I just want to get an idea of how I should set it up. So if I get a wifi adapter and configure the second VM to use that adapter, I should be able to scan the network using the 'iwlist' command. That should return the SSID, channel number, and MAC address correct?

Comment: You may need to install drivers but many are plug and play. Once working yes, you should be able to scan.